# how to insert sum of all categories into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have data like this

```
  category        expense       monthyear
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1. food           1000           Dec2015
2.  movie          100            Dec2015
3.  housing        2000           Dec2015
4  .food           1000           Dec2015
5  .housing        2000           Dec2015
6.  food           1000           Dec2015
```

When I insert into database I want to get the sum of each category expense to the database like: `food-3000,movie-100,housing-4000`

How to write the query,im doing it in `codeigniter` framework?

Comment: yes when i am inserting to the database,same time sum of each category insertion to another table.two insert queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the basic query structure that you want is:

```
INSERT INTO expensetotals (category_total, exp_total)
SELECT category AS category_total, SUM(expense) AS exp_total
FROM expenses
GROUP BY category
```

where the new table "expensetotals" looks like this:

```
category_total       exp_total
------------------------------
food                 3000
housing              4000
movie                100
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with CodeIgnitor, but according to your question, you can try this query

```
  INSERT INTO categorysum(category, amount) SELECT category, sum(expense) FROM current_table WHERE 1 GROUP BY category
```